# How to pick and save an image from the gallery (AndroidStudio)?

Tags: android, imageview, save

I have just no idea how to do that. 
Well, I can pick an image from the gallery and display it in an imageView. I did that with uri of that image. 
But I dont know how to save it so that when I run the app again my image will show up. 
I tried to save the URI with converting it to a String and saved it with sharedPrefs. But it doenst work.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

you can set it as background if you want to show it when you open your app

Comment: You mean as a background of the imageView ? How can I do that in java?

Comment: yes , so it will showed every time you open the app

Comment: Should I use uri to set the background?

Comment: you cn use uri imageview.setImageURI(path); , or the image itself imageview.setimagebitmap(bitmap) as you like

Comment: The thing is: I used sharedPrefs to store the path. How do I get the URI from the string? I tried :    savedImageUri = Uri.parse(savedImageUriString);      but it doesnt work